# How to get username and password from database before user is authenticated

Tags: azure, authentication, ionic-framework, nuget-package

I am using the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login NuGet package with ionic and visual studios to add custom authentication. The problem is I must check with my database whether or not the username and password is correct, but the user is not authenticated yet so I receive a 401 unauthorized request. How do I get around this?

Comment: Don't do that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably what to implement a promise. So when the user registers? ( i am guessing this is for registration ) you first search against the current db and the login details. This needs to return ( you can have a loading icon or something while that is happening ) then write a condition based on the return. The conditional statement only executing when the promise is returned and your logic for redirect ( or other , not sure 100% about the final outcome you want ) or rather what ever sets the 401 can be skipped in the if else

```
  checkUser(userDetails).then(returnedVal => {
    if(returnedVal){
      // user exists
    }else{
     // user does not exist
    }
  });
```

The user does or does not exist in the Db. First check for that . Does the user exist , a singular operation with no other core functionality. Then work your code against the outcome of that single operation.